# Dash error while returning an array : Invalid argument Expected `object`. Was supplied type `string`

Tags: python, json, types, callback, plotly-dash

I am learning and using Dash for my company and I find it really hard to understand.
I am trying to load a DataFrame and retrieve the index of these DF.
I can have 2 types of indexes:
Date bases:

```
['01/08/2019', '02/08/2019', '03/08/2019', '04/08/2019', '05/08/2019', '06/08/2019', '07/08/2019', '08/08/2019', '09/08/2019', '10/08/2019', '11/08/2019', '12/08/2019', '13/08/2019', '14/08/2019', '15/08/2019', '16/08/2019', '17/08/2019', '18/08/2019', '19/08/2019', '20/08/2019', '21/08/2019', '22/08/2019', '23/08/2019', '24/08/2019', '25/08/2019', '26/08/2019', '27/08/2019', '28/08/2019', '29/08/2019', '30/08/2019', '31/08/2019']
```

Name based:

```
['CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000071608', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000464753', 'CARD0000550035', 'CARD0000550035', 'CARD0000550035', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30000210731689', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001441205960', 'PRM30001640097183', 'PRM30001640097183', 'PRM30001640097183', 'PRM30001640097183', 'PRM30001640097183', 'PRM30001640097183']
```

This is the error i'm getting:

> Invalid argument `options[0]` passed into Dropdown with ID "index-df".
>   Expected `object`.
>   Was supplied type `string`.

I'd like to be able to return a dict like that: `{'csv': index}` or  `{'txt': index}` so I can take different action if the file is a csv or a txt.

I tried to store my index in an **array or a dict** called  `index`.
I tried to use `json.dumps(index)` to serialize my array/dict storing my indexes, but it did not work. I don't understand where the problem is and I spent at least 5 hours trying to figure this problem out. Dash should be able to deal with Strings right? I made sure to convert my values to String but it does not work. It tried to use JSON but it does not work.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import json

import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from functions_definition import list_every_file
from functions_definition import load_file

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


# list every csv and txt files
FILE_LIST = list_every_file('../data', ['csv', 'TXT'])

# list the files with their extension (csv or txt)
DICT_EXTENSION = {}
txt_arr = []
csv_arr = []
for item in FILE_LIST:
    if item[-3:].lower() == 'txt':
        txt_arr.append(item)
    else:
        csv_arr.append(item)
DICT_EXTENSION['txt'] = txt_arr
DICT_EXTENSION['csv'] = csv_arr

markdown_intro = '''
### File selection 

1. Please select the type of file (TXT or CSV) you want to open.   
'''

markdown_intro_2 = '''
2. Please select the file you want to open.   
'''

markdown_intro_3 = '''
3. Please select the day.   
'''

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Markdown(children=markdown_intro),

    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='filetype-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in DICT_EXTENSION.keys()],
        value='txt'
    ),

    html.Hr(),

    dcc.Markdown(children=markdown_intro_2),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='file-selection',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in FILE_LIST],
        value=FILE_LIST[0],          # default value
        clearable=False
    ),

    html.Hr(),

    dcc.Markdown(children=markdown_intro_3),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='index-df')

])

# choose between 'txt' and 'csv'
@app.callback(
    Output('file-selection', 'options'),
    [Input('filetype-dropdown', 'value')])
def set_cities_options(selected_country):
    #print("type = ", type([{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in DICT_EXTENSION[selected_country]]))
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in DICT_EXTENSION[selected_country]]



@app.callback(
    Output('index-df', 'options'),
    [Input('file-selection', 'value')])
def set_cities_options(selected_df):
    selected_df = str(selected_df)

    file_name = selected_df[0:-4]
    extension = (selected_df[-3:]).lower()
    df = load_file('../data/' + file_name, extension)

    index = []
    if extension == 'csv':
        for i in range(len(df)):
            index.append(df.index[i][0])

    else:
        index = df.index
        index = index.values.tolist()

    print(index)
    print(type(index))
    return index

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Maybe the error is due to `value=FILE_LIST[0]` in the **Dropdown** with the id `file-selection`. But if I don't put this line, the first time the program loads, it loads None instead of a file, making the program bug. I don't know what to do with a None value, that's why I put a default value.

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this?